# Uniqueness of a number in a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, unique

I have written this code so far (which i found here in Stack Overflow and altered a bit)

```
unique(M,List) :- 
 append(X,Y,List),
 member(M,X),
 member(M,Y).
```

But it does the exact opposite of what i want.

for example, it is expected to give these results.

```
?- unique(1,[1,2,3]).
yes

?- unique(1,[1,2,3,1]).
no
```

but instead, it gives

```
?- unique(1,[1,2,3]).
no

?- unique(1,[1,2,3,1]).
yes
```

is there a way in which i can modify my code in order to give the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Your code effectively says "M is unique in List if List can be split into two parts, X and Y, and M is present in both X and Y." This is a very clever way of doing exactly the opposite of what you want.

Here's another way of asking if X is unique in List: if I take X from List, X is no longer in List. You could turn that into Prolog like so:

```
unique(X, List) :-
    select(X, List, ListWithoutX),
    \+ memberchk(X, ListWithoutX).
```